# Is there a phrase in English that means an apology for banality?

Tags: phrases

In Russian there is a phrase that literally means "sorry for triviality (banality)". It is used when a person wants to say something very simple and common like "everyone is mortal" or "love is the cure", etc. Is there something like that in English and if it is, how often do people use it?

Comment: I *have* heard and used a facetious "--to coin a phrase" as a conversational tag to whereby the speaker acknowledges, or someone else gently points out, that the sentiment just expressed is a hoary old saying.

Comment: Sorry for the trite remark!

Comment: A similar apology that can have several meanings is: "If you'll pardon the expression..."

Comment: @Sergey, would you mind sharing the Russian phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to distance oneself from a word or phrase is to include hedging phrases to indicate that they are not your own; they are a proverb or slogan or buzzword that someone else might normally use, which you are only borrowing. It may not be because the phrase is trite— it may be offensive, for example— but the conceit is the same.

> They won the contract and the rest, *[as they say](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_they_say)*, is history.
>
> She finally passed on last Thursday. And frankly, *[as the saying goes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/as-or-so-the-saying-goes-or-is)*, ding-dong, the witch is dead.
>
> The in-flight was the absolute worst, [something special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines#Slogans) in the air, *[so to speak](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/so-to-speak)*.

There usually aren't names or faces for the *they* in *[that's what they say](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/42/c4/d8/42c4d80a29f7848043b9996769c4a700.jpg)*, but there are many variations that do: *as the kids would say*, *as the French say*, *as Obama might say*, and so on.

But these phrases are not really used *apologetically*, i.e. the speaker is not directly apologizing for his or her use of the phrasing, merely acknowledging that it is applicable to the situation. To apologize, you would need to make an apology:

> If you'll excuse the cliché, money talks.
>
> Pardon the expression, but there's more than one way to skin a cat.
>
> Sorry to put it this way, but no pain, no gain.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "sorry to state the obvious" would work very well, as in the case of this headline in The Atlantic:

https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2009/07/sorry-to-state-the-obvious-but/22147/